# WebRTC Acoustic Echo cancelation

Tags: javascript, webrtc, aec

I'm currently working on webrtc project, and having a problem with audio echo when not using an earphone, or external mic, is there any work around or fix for this

Comment: WebRTC is a P2P data transfer protocol and has nothing in common with audio.

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph you're thinking of RTCPeerConnection. For historical reasons, WebRTC is often used as an umbrella term for both that and the `getUserMedia` API. Even peer connections aren't data-agnostic, and deal specifically with audio and video.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there's no best solution for echo cancelation in webrtc, so the best solution i found is using AEC software, or built in echo cancelation software

Answer (score 7):

Echo cancellation is supposed to be on by default in WebRTC. You can turn it off to hear the difference:

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: { echoCancellation: false } })
  .then(stream => audio.srcObject = stream)
  .catch(e => log(e));

var log = msg => div.innerHTML += msg + "<br>";
```

```html
<audio id="audio" controls autoplay></audio><br>
<div id="div"></div>
<script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
```

Echo cancellation technology can exist at many levels - software in the browser, in the OS, and sometimes even in your hardware mic - sometimes these technologies can interfere with each other.

Not knowing your system, I would recommend checking out your system's sounds settings to make sure you don't have helpful processing happening at too many levels.

For example, on OSX, there's a *use ambient noise reduction* feature under *Sound Settings* that unintuitively works better for me with WebRTC when I turn ***off***. You only want one chef attempting echo cancellation at the same time.

If you are working on a web site for other clients, then there's not much you can do in software, and I would expect most systems to work, if not perfectly, decently well, though a headset will always be better.

Comment: yes i have no problem if i use a headset, but the echo still exist if i didn't use it because my voice returned from other people speaker and that cause echo or feedback, have any other solution for this ?.

Comment: @ShinjiKagehisa what browser, system and microphone?

Comment: chrome, firefox using osx, windows, linux and builtin microphone

Comment: @ShinjiKagehisa actually, if you're hearing your voice returned from other people's speakers then maybe the echo is on *their* system. I would try different participants to isolate where the echo is coming from (I know you mentioned headphones fixing it which is what's confusing).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same trouble even with the video *echoCancellation* constraint

I could finally delete the echo/noise adding the property `muted="true"` to your **local** video element and set up the volume to 0 `document.getElementById("localVideo").volume = 0`

That will not prevent your localStream to have the sound but it'll cancel the noise you have locally.