# Audio recording remove noise

Tags: webrtc, noise

I have a problem with audio recording in JavaScript.
Everything is working, when the computers are far away, but when they approach each other, the voice coming out of the speaker is heard on the other side's loudspeaker and the sound begins to jump in a closed cycle. There is a noise at the turn of the time, which turns into an unbearable loophole.

The server is written in node.js.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please mention the code with issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to move the computers close to each other. What kind of application are you working with.

If you *really* need it, then look for an echo cancellation module a add it to your pipeline. But  you will loose some degree of quality anyway.

To knwo about WebRTC echo cancellation, you can start here:

[WebRTC Acoustic Echo cancelation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37390574/webrtc-acoustic-echo-cancelation)

Comment: can You send worked link in echo cancellation software on javascript

Comment: Thank you very much